# Shadow and outline in button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

i want put a shadow in my button, but when i put a outline in the title, the outline have a shadow, and i want put shadow only in the text.

This is my code that i use in my button:

```
NSShadow *shadow = [NSShadow new];
[shadow setShadowColor:self.shadowColor];
[shadow setShadowOffset:self.offset];
UIColor* strokeColor = self.outlineColor;
UIColor* fontColor = [self titleColorForState:UIControlStateNormal];
NSAttributedString *attributedText =
[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.titleLabel.text
                                attributes:@{
                                            NSShadowAttributeName:shadow,
                                            NSStrokeWidthAttributeName:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(-1 * self.outlineWidth)],
                                            NSStrokeColorAttributeName: strokeColor,
                                            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: fontColor}];
[self setAttributedTitle:attributedText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

So is i want to show the title of button:
[image: Title of button]

Comment: What's the question? What's not going right, and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find a solution for this question, i used the next code:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];
    CGRect rectt = self.titleLabel.frame;
    rect = rectt;
    rectt.origin.y += self.offset.height;
    rectt.origin.x += self.offset.width;

    UIColor *borderColor = [self.outlineColor copy];
    UIColor *fillColor = self.titleLabel.textColor;
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if (self.drawShadow) {
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 0.0f);
        CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFillStroke);
        [self setTitleColor:self.shadow forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.titleLabel drawTextInRect:rectt];
    }

    if (self.drawOutline) {
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.outlineWidth);
        CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextStroke);
        [self setTitleColor:borderColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.titleLabel drawTextInRect:self.titleLabel.frame];
    }

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 0.0f);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFillStroke);
    [self setTitleColor:fillColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self.titleLabel drawTextInRect:self.titleLabel.frame];
}
```

My class is inherited of UIButton

Comment: This is wrong. You are not invited to override UIButton's `drawRect`.

Comment: Because is wrong. i don't understand the why is wrong @matt

Comment: You should not override UIButton `drawRect:`, and you should never call UILabel's `drawTextInRect:`. Everything you're doing is forbidden.

Comment: Ok, so now if you know right way, please tell me.
Because this is the only solution that i found.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do what you want is to stack two instances of your text on top of each other.  The bottom one has no outline, but casts the narrow shadow that you want.  The one on top has the outline and no shadow.

Comment: If this helped you, can you give me a +1 ? Thanks!